# How to handle input in Flask with indexes inside name?

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

How to handle inputs form like these:

```
<input type="text" name="time[1]" value="a">
<input type="text" name="time[2]" value="h">
<input type="text" name="time[3]" value="j">
```

I tried to get values of inputs using the following approach:

```
for index, time in enumerate(request.form.getlist('time[]')):
   pass
```

As a result I have to get `value` and index inside `time[]`.

For example, when I send only a one field:

```
<input type="text" name="time[3]" value="3">
```

I should get `value=j` and `index=3`

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Flask (or to any backend for that matter) those parameters are sent as individual form arguments called `time[1]`, `time[2]` and `time[3]`, not as some sort of a magical list. If you want to turn them into a `list`, or rather a `dict` as it's a sparse list, then you'll have to loop through your `request.form` and *extract* them. Something like:

```
form = request.form  # a short-hand for readability 
time = {p[5:-1]: form[p] for p in form if p[:4] == "time" and p[4] == "[" and p[-1] == "]"}
```

Then you can use the newly created `time` dictionary to loop through each of the parameters in an `index:value` manner:

```
for i, v in time.items():
    print("index={}, value={}".format(i, v))
```

Or you can access your index directly to obtain the value, i.e. `time['3']`. Notice that we're using strings as indexes here, if sent 'indexes' are **always** integers, you can use `int(p[5:-1])` when setting the key and then access the value with `time[3]`.

If you want to use `request.form.getlist()` you'll need to name all your inputs the same (e.g. `time[]`) but then you won't have sparse lists.

Comment: Maybe to use another way? For example send data otherwise?

Comment: @Jessie - as I've said in the end, if you name all your inputs `time[]` then you'll be able to retrieve a list using `request.form.getlist("time[]")` but that means that you won't be able to detect which of those inputs was not sent - you'll just get a `0..n` indexed list containing individual values of all the `input` fields with name `time[]`, sent to your Flask app.

Comment: Soç then İ can not to get index of each input

Comment: @Jessie - you can with the code above, you cannot if you use `time[]` as a name for each input.

Comment: Can you recommend hot to make it more easy? I mean how to change HTML code for convenience handling data? Maybe set checkboxes near inputs?

Comment: Well, you can use checkboxes but then you would need to go through all checkbox fields to see which index is turned on and which is not, and then post-process your list accordingly. I don't see what's hard about the above approach - you'll be getting exactly what you wanted and the overhead is minimal.